# Notion Formula how to set a link with webhooks?

Tags: formula, webhooks, make.com, notion

To connect to the concept I need webhooks from make.com. I don't know why I can't do this?
a link with webhooks should appear in the column, but it doesn't. Can any of you make such a connection? This is my first time working with these tools and I can't find any advice anywhere.